# Control outputs / signal queue in CONNECT platform?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to prevent an empty item to go through to an object (in this case at the end of the list to simplify the case). Does the control output "signals" have any kind of queue where they are consumed or is it going to trigger the node if the signal is sent at least once?

The question is specific to this example where it is returning an empty object at the end which it shouldn't be but I am still interested to know how control outputs behave in different scenarios (this being one such interesting scenario). In a normal case, the array would be first filtered to eliminate any "incompatible" (e.g undefined) elements.

[image: Example CONNECT platform iteration and control output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- there is no queue for control signals. all control signals of a node must activate in order for the node to activate as well though.
- once a node finishes its execution, its control flag is reset, but its data input pins are not. as a result, the control signals should all be emitted again for the node to activate, however the parameters it received via its input pins will persist.
- when you resend data to an input pin, the previous value will be overridden, so for the next execution of the node, the overridden value will be used. note that the node will still wait for all control signals to green-light the execution.

these should answer your question generally. but to be more specific to the use-case you have at hand: you are forgetting that these nodes execute asynchronously, and probably thats why your graph is not behaving as you desire. this is how that could occur:

1. `#iterate` will feed a step with non empty `item` to the expression.
2. the expression will feed this step to the switch and to `/user/key/delete`.
3. `#iterate` will feed another step, this time with an empty `item` to the expression.
4. the expression will feed `false` to `/user/key/delete`.
5. the switch will give a green-light to `/user/key/delete` when it finishes its previous execution (with the non-empty step).

as you can see, you would then have `/user/key/delete` be executed on `false`, which is something that it seems you want to avoid. to side-step this issue, I would recommend simply filtering the array before feeding it to `#iterate` to begin with.

a clearer example of this phenomenon can be seen with a graph like this:

[image]

running this sub-graph will lead to 3 numbers being printed, but not necessarily even numbers, due to the same phenomenon.